# Google Dataflow - ability to parallelize the work in the currently running step

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am tring to run google dataflow for a simulatio process. I tried to initiate dataflow by max worker nodes 5 with auto-scaling on (THROUGHPUT_BASED).

Issue is that dataflow is not utilizing all the worker nodes (5) ad giving me message.

Autoscaling: Reduced the number of workers to 1 based on the ability to parallelize the work in the currently running step(s).

Please suggest what can be the issue.

Logs are attached below.

> 2017-05-10T06:01:36.555Z: Detail:  (5de468ab73bd7581): Autoscaling is
>   enabled for job 2017-05-09_23_01_36-6765647625807820060. The number of
>   workers will be between 1 and 1000. 2017-05-10T06:01:37.811Z: Detail: 
>   (feb335244b957ccc): Checking required Cloud APIs are enabled.
>   2017-05-10T06:02:05.328Z: Detail:  (feb335244b9573fd): Expanding
>   GroupByKey operations into optimizable parts.
>   2017-05-10T06:02:05.332Z: Detail:  (feb335244b957017): Lifting
>   ValueCombiningMappingFns into MergeBucketsMappingFns
>   2017-05-10T06:02:05.714Z: Detail:  (feb335244b957a72): Fusing adjacent
>   ParDo, Read, Write, and Flatten operations 2017-05-10T06:02:05.716Z:
>   Detail:  (feb335244b95768c): Fusing consumer AnonymousParDo into
>   Read/DataflowPipelineRunner.BatchBigQueryIONativeRead
>   2017-05-10T06:02:05.718Z: Detail:  (feb335244b9572a6): Fusing consumer
>   WriteToBigQuery/DataflowPipelineRunner.BatchBigQueryIOWrite/DataflowPipelineRunner.BatchBigQueryIONativeWrite
>   into AnonymousParDo 2017-05-10T06:02:05.728Z: Detail: 
>   (feb335244b95730e): Adding StepResource setup and teardown to workflow
>   graph. 2017-05-10T06:02:05.767Z: Basic:  (75edc98e2ecf8a50): Executing
>   operation
>   Read/DataflowPipelineRunner.BatchBigQueryIONativeRead+AnonymousParDo+WriteToBigQuery/DataflowPipelineRunner.BatchBigQueryIOWrite/DataflowPipelineRunner.BatchBigQueryIONativeWrite
>   2017-05-10T06:02:05.973Z: Basic:  (c9b9bc749d188107): Starting 5
>   workers... 2017-05-10T06:02:07.735Z: Basic:  (4903a2f536f5c1ae):
>   BigQuery query issued as job: "dataflow_job_4354447435307355184". You
>   can check its status with the bq tool: "bq show -j
>   --project_id=com-dl-parts-dev dataflow_job_4354447435307355184". 2017-05-10T06:03:03.727Z: Detail:  (376dc1d89cc4c16e): Workers have
>   started successfully. 2017-05-10T06:04:09.561Z: Basic: 
>   (4903a2f536f5c868): BigQuery query completed, job :
>   "dataflow_job_4354447435307355184" 2017-05-10T06:04:09.987Z: Basic: 
>   (4903a2f536f5cfbf): BigQuery export job
>   "dataflow_job_5261227963771635305" started. You can check its status
>   with the bq tool: "bq show -j --project_id=com-dl-parts-dev
>   dataflow_job_5261227963771635305". 2017-05-10T06:05:10.798Z: Detail: 
>   (d0c3fbda1e314661): BigQuery export job progress:
>   "dataflow_job_5261227963771635305" observed total of 1 exported files
>   thus far. 2017-05-10T06:05:10.801Z: Basic:  (d0c3fbda1e31498f):
>   BigQuery export job finished: "dataflow_job_5261227963771635305"
>   2017-05-10T06:06:12.303Z: Basic:  (d51372b306784d58): Autoscaling:
>   Resized worker pool from 5 to 1. 2017-05-10T06:06:12.306Z: Detail: 
>   (d51372b306784f56): Autoscaling: Reduced the number of workers to 1
>   based on the rate of progress in the currently running step(s).
>   2017-05-10T06:07:38.000Z: Basic:  (4e3c32839262218d): Autoscaling:
>   Attempting to upscale worker pool to 2. 2017-05-10T06:08:11.074Z:
>   Basic:  (4e3c328392622142): Autoscaling: Resized worker pool from 1 to
>   2. 2017-05-10T06:08:11.077Z: Detail:  (4e3c32839262213c): Autoscaling: Raised the number of workers to 2 based on the ability to parallelize
>   the work in the currently running step(s). 2017-05-10T06:13:41.023Z:
>   Basic:  (ae82479176c127a3): Autoscaling: Resized worker pool from 2 to
>   1. 2017-05-10T06:13:41.027Z: Detail:  (ae82479176c129d5): Autoscaling: Reduced the number of workers to 1 based on the ability to parallelize
>   the work in the currently running step(s). 2017-05-10T06:20:31.844Z:
>   Basic:  (a41dfc71af8c36fd): Executing BigQuery import job
>   "dataflow_job_4354447435307352182". You can check its status with the
>   bq tool: "bq show -j --project_id=com-dl-parts-dev
>   dataflow_job_4354447435307352182".

**Update:-** Is it right way to prevent fusion?

I am reading a Bigquery table using bigquery IO. This input parameter gives me product number in each record.

After I am doing a ParDo operation. Within process element function I am doing some data forecast operations for each product that I am getting from input.

```
PCollection<TableRow> quotes3 = quotes2.apply(ParDo.of(new  DoFn<TableRow, TableRow>() {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception{

        TableRow rowData = c.element();
        rowData = c.element();
        TableRow tableRowData = ForcastOperation(rowData);
        c.output(tableRowDRP);
    }
}));
```

In last step I am dumping the forcast result into bigquery using dataflow pipeline.

```
quotes3.apply(BigQueryIO.Write
        .named("WriteToBigQuery")
        .to("com-dl-parts:ds_parts.output_data")
        .withSchema(schema)
        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));

pipelineTransform.run();
```

**Update :-  17/05/2017 13:38**

I am tring to break the fusion by below listed way. It scaled up the GroupByKey apply operation to 308 nodes. but I am not sure it is scaling up the secound pardo having ForcastOperation method to 308 nodes.

```
 PCollection<String> quotes1 = quotes.apply(ParDo.of(new  DoFn<TableRow, KV<String, String>>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Random random = new Random();

        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception{
            TableRow rowData = c.element();
            rowData = c.element();
            c.output(KV.of(rowData.get("APRODUCT").toString(), rowData.get("APRODUCT").toString()));
        }
        })).apply(GroupByKey.<String, String>create())
           .apply(Values.<Iterable<String>>create())
           .apply(Flatten.<String>iterables());



PCollection<TableRow> quotes3 = quotes1.apply(ParDo.of(new  DoFn<String, TableRow>() {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception{

        TableRow rowData = c.element();
        rowData = c.element();
        TableRow tableRowData = ForcastOperation(rowData);
        c.output(tableRowDRP);
    }
}));
```

In last step I am dumping the forcast result into bigquery using dataflow pipeline.

```
    quotes3.apply(BigQueryIO.Write
        .named("WriteToBigQuery")
        .to("com-dl-parts:ds_parts.output_data")
        .withSchema(schema)
        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));

pipelineTransform.run();
```

Comment: Please provide insights into how the pipeline is structured. Post that we can help you identify issues (if any) within the step so that your job can be massively parallelised!

Comment: What exactly is the problem/question? With autoscaling on, you're telling Dataflow to pick the best number of works that it deems fit for the amount of data it needs to process. This is a normal message to receive as workers come in/out of the pool. In your case, Dataflow made the decision to run with just 1 worker. I'm guessing because the data size/volume isn't that big.

Comment: Hi Graham, My requirement is to run 1000 nodes in parallel for each product that I am fetching form first query in quotes2 dataflow pipeline. I assumption is that 1000 nodes should process pardo first 1000 product in parallel and so no. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I still don't get it. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the logs of this job and it appears that the amount of data it has read from BigQuery as input is extremely small - on the order of 1kb. Is this expected?

If yes, and if you still want to parallelize processing of your 1kb 1000-ways, then I assume your ForecastOperation function is extremely computationally intensive per element.

In that case you need to break fusion between reading from BigQuery and applying ForecastOperation. Please see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#preventing-fusion

Comment: Hi jkff, I tried to prevent fusion. Can you guide me further on how to prevent fusion, I tried on approach as I updated today in the question. Please provide your valuable comments.

Comment: The code looks mostly reasonable, what's the job ID? (in general, when asking about the performance about a Dataflow job, please always provide the job ID, otherwise I can't locate the job and can't look at how it executed)

Comment: Job name 
ps58kntlvl170520171504
Job ID 
2017-05-17_07_08_33-11047569556279833573   -- I canceled this job later as it was scaled down from 1000 worker nodes to 19 only.

Comment: One More - Job name 
ps58kntlvl170520170752
Job ID 
2017-05-16_23_56_27-5552617165052747923

Comment: How many elements does your dataset have? From what I see it seems like it has only 19 elements, so it is algorithmically impossible to parallelize the processing more than 19 ways (best you can do is process each element in parallel, right?). If you tell more about what that operation does, and if it is algorithmically parallelizable, I might give advice on how to express it as a PTransform which Dataflow will be able to parallelize.

Comment: Side note: it's unfortunate that Dataflow upsized the job to 1000 worker nodes - though it quickly discovered that there's not enough parallelizable work available to warrant keeping 1000 workers around, and downsized, but the original upsizing decision was overly aggressive. We'll look into that.

Comment: Ok - Operation is I am fetching 58k (measn 58k records from BQ) parts from bigquery. So for each part I have to do some heavy operation in pardo (it will take around 10 to 15 min for computation and generate lot of data to write back in bigqiery). So the problem is that input data is 58k is very few around 2 MB and output is in GB's of data. Some time I am also getting exception DEADLINE_EXCEEDED after using GroupbyKey. Is there any way to control dataflow autoscaling according to put requirements? My requirement is that for each part my process will run on separate worker node.

Comment: I am confused by some inconsistencies between what you say here, what you say in the question, and what I see in the pipeline's logs. Here you say you have 58k records; in the logs I see that there's only a handful of different keys (less than 20); and the code in the question is confusing because in "quotes3" you are applying a DoFn<String, TableRow>, but you're using c.element() as a TableRow, not as a String. Can you provide a more complete sample of the code you're actually running to construct the pipeline? Also, how many *distinct* values of APRODUCT does your dataset have?

Comment: Hi jkff, Point number 1 - Please see Job name 
ps58kntlvl170520170649 Job ID 2017-05-16_22_54_36-1239409962845803804  - In read operation you can see 58022 records.      Point 2 - distinct APRODUCTs are 58022. Point 3 - I will provide full code in update of the question above. or let me know your email Id I will send you file.

Comment: Hmm, okay, another question: did you consider adding logging to your ForecastOperation - i.e. LOG.info right before and right after invoking it? It could be that most APRODUCTs are processed extremely quickly, but a handful of them take a very long time. That would explain the poor parallelization as well and would explain why I'm seeing only a handful of keys being processed.

Comment: Also, I assume you've already tried this, but just in case: were you able to successfully run this pipeline, with good performance and correct results, on small subsets of the full dataset using Direct runner?